# C# List of strings getting an Indexoutofrange Error

Tags: c#, string, list, parsing

I have the following string, which I split and store into a List of strings. Afterwards when I'm going to use these elements, I am getting an error of "Indexoutofrange" but how is this possible ?

the string:

```
"getName():String
getTitle():String
getStaffNo():Int
getRoom():String
getPhone()"
```

my code:

```
List<myObject> myObjectList = new List<myObject>();

// in valueList Im now storing the string input and also split them at the whitespaces
List<string> valueList = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(stringValue, @"\s{2,}").ToList<string>();

foreach (string stringValue in valueList)
{
   // in tmp variable I'm splitting the stored string at ':' because the left side of the split is the name of the object und the right side is the type
   var tmp = stringValue.Split(':');
   myObject object1 = new myObject()
   {
      object1.name = tmp[0];
      object1.type = tmp[1];
   };

   myObjectList.Add(object1);
}
```

After I just run my unit Test Im getting all **object.name** right, so *"getName"*, *"getTitle"*, *"getStaffNo"*, *"getRoom"* and *"getPhone"* are correctly stored in each object but the **type** refers to an error => **"IndexOutOfRangeException"**.
I just can't explain the exception because there should be at **tmp[1]** the value *"String"* stored

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: Can you modify your code to be valid C# that will compile? If I fix the syntax errors, I get no `IndexOutOfRangeException` which likely means your source string is not what you think it is.

Comment: *there should be at tmp[1] the value "String" stored* ... obviously not. What does the debugger tell you about the value in `stringValue` and that `tmp` array? That should give you (and us) some clue. See also: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Ok, I just found my problem, it was in the string because there was also one item without a type like "getPhone()" there was no ':' or "String" and at this point, the program just got crashed.